# Compare ParentViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I want to change the header text on a view depending on where it has come from (so depending on the parentViewController).

Is there a way to say: if the parent view controller is viewControllerX?

For now I've added a protocol to viewControllerX and I'm doing

```
if ([self.parentViewController confromsToProcol:@protocol(vcX)])
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about ViewController instances of the same class you can add a property to the class (for example 'myInstanceName' and set it's value different for each instance.

```
#define kInstanceNameFoo @"myInstanceFoo"

FooClassName *pvc = (FooClassName *)self.parentViewController;
if (pvc.myInstanceName == kInstanceNameFoo) {
```

If the ViewControllers are actually different classes you can use the "class" property to compare.

```
if (self.parentViewController.class == [FooClassName class]) {
```

Comment: The second part was what I needed.